# Create a new variable for each time point in R

Tags: r, apply, longitudinal

I have a wide dataset with variables measured at different time points. Each variable has many columns in the dataset and the number at the end of the columns indicates de timepoint when the data was collected (ex. a.1 , a.2,  a.3 etc). I would like to create a new variable for each timepoint, using the same formula on the same variables. How could I code this by using only one formula applied for each time point, instead of repeating the same code for each timepoint, as in the example below?

```
df$a.1 <- (df$b.1 + df$c.1)/2

df$a.2 <- (df$b.2 + df$c.2)/2

df$a.3 <- (df$b.3 + df$c.3)/2

df$a.4 <- (df$b.4 + df$c.4)/2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could subset the `b` columns, get the corresponding `c` columns and do the mean and assign back to new columns, `paste` is vectorized as well as `+` and `/`

```
df[paste0("a.", 1:4)] <- (df[paste0("b.", 1:4)] + df[paste0("c.", 1:4)])/2
```

---

It may also be possible with `across` by looping over the 'b', columns, then `get` the corresponding 'c' columns and change the names in `.names` to create new columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df <- df %>%
      mutate(across(starts_with('b.'), ~ 
                (. + get(str_replace(cur_column(), 'b', 'c')))/2,
              .names = "{str_replace(.col, 'b', 'a')}"))
```

Comment: Thanks Akrun! It worked. Then I tried to apply the same process for another new variable ("e") that I want to create from the mean of 4 variables ("a", "b", "c" and "d") instead of 2 ("a" and "b") variables, but I could not make it work. Here is the code I tried, but obviously I got something wrong...    df <- df %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with('a.'), ~
                  (. + get(str_replace(cur_column(), 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd')))/4,
                .names = "{str_replace(.col, 'a', 'e')}"))

Comment: @Myriam the second code works only when you have two cases.  If you have more cases, you need multiple `str_replace` i.e. `get(str_replace(cur_column(), 'b', 'c')) + `get(str_replace(cur_column(), 'b', 'd')) + ...`. Instead it may be easier in the first case i..e just subset for `c', 'd', 'e' with `paste`

Comment: @Myriam i.e. your code `str_replace(cur_column(), 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd')` is incorrect because the `str_replace` usage is `str_replace(string, pattern, replacement)` and when you provide more arguments than it is there in the function, it breaks

Comment: @Myriam An option in `tidyverse` is also to reshape to 'long' format with `pivot_longer` i.e. `df %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% pivot_longer(cols = -rn, names_to = c(".value", "grp"), names_sep = "\\.") %>% mutate(a = (b + c+d + e)/4) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = grp, values_from = c(a, b, c, d, e)) %>% select(-rn)`

Comment: @Myriam please note that I didn't test the above code in pivot_longer.  There could be some mistakes in it.  Sorry